# How find this system equation with Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory

Let $f(n)$ is smallest the positive integers greater than $n$ that are non-Coprime to $n$, in other words,
$f(n)=\{(f(n))_\min\mid\gcd(f(n),n)>1,f(n)>n\}$

solve this following system 
$$\begin{cases}
f(n)=m\\
\varphi(m)=n\\
m,n\in N^{+}
\end{cases}$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is [Euler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

I have found $f(2)=4$ and $\varphi(4)=2$ is one solution

Comment: Please note the use of \mid and \min in f(n)=\{(f(n))_\min\mid\gcd(f(n),n)>1,f(n)>n\}.  I edited accordingly. Using \mid results in proper spacing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think it's better to write:$$f(n)=\min\{x\in\Bbb N^+\mid\gcd(x,n)>1,x>n\}$$

Answer (score 0):

The first integer which are not coprime with $n$ is the smallest prime which divides $n$ denoted by $p(n)$, hence the first integer which is not coprime with $n$ and greater then $n$ is $n+p(n)$. hence $$f(n)=n+p(n)$$

Given $(n,m)$ satisfying your system we have:
$$\begin{align}n+p(n)&=m\\
\varphi(m)& =n \end{align}$$

hence $\varphi(m)=m-p$ with $p=p(n)$  let's write $m=qp$ (because $p$ divides $m$)and this implies that:
$$\varphi(qp)=p(q-1)$$
Now using the well know inequality:
$$\varphi(n)\leq n-\sqrt{n} $$
for non prime integers $n$ we have $p(q-1)\leq pq-\sqrt{pq}$ hence $\sqrt{pq}\leq p$ we conclude that $q \leq p$, But we know that $n=m-p=p(q-1)$ and because $p$ is the smallest prime which divides $n$ we have $p\leq q$ hence $p=q$.

Finally $m=p^2$ and $n=p(p-1)$ for some prime $p$, but $p$ must be the smallest divisor which divides $n$ then $p-1=1$ and $p=2,m=4$

Comment: It's Nice answer!+1